# Get rid of HTML tags in a block in Smarty

Tags: html, tags, smarty, block

How can I get rid of HTML tags in a Smarty block?
I've tried `{strip}` within the block and it did not work.
Also I tried to write a plugin. But how can I parse the content of a block into a string variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `{strip}` block actually does something else - it only strips whitespace off markup.

You could write a simple block plugin:

```
function smarty_block_sanitize($parms, $content, &$smarty, &$repeat ) {
    if( $repeat ) {
        return( strip_tags( $content ) );
    }
}
```

Put this somewhere in a PHP file called before displaying the template. To use it in template, do this:

```
Sample text {sanitize}<more markup>test</more markup>{/sanitize}  End text.
```

Beware allowing tags with strip_tags (with its PHP parameter), since onclick / onmouseover / other wicked attributes do not get filtered.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`{capture}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl) a block to a variable and then use PHP's [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) on it:

```
{capture name="withtags"}
    <em>Text</em> with <strong>tags</strong>
{/capture}
{$smarty.capture.withtags|strip_tags}
```